# Pip installing via cmd has no effect

Tags: python

Ok, so I'm trying to install Tweepy onto my computer through Pip. I've uninstalled and reinstalled Pip itself, and have checked to see if it's in my python35-32/Scripts folder: it is. I go to the command line, enter `pip install tweepy`, and cross my fingers.

Nothing happens. The command line moves down two lines, around a second passes, and the process ends. When I try to "import" tweepy in a script, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy 
ImportError: No module named 'tweepy'
```

I don't know if I'm missing a crucial step in the process, or if there's some obvious solution I haven't noticed. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Also, this happens with whatever I put in after `pip`, whether or not it is a valid command.

EDIT: I am using Widows 10. `python --version` returns Python 3.5.0, while `pip --version` gives the same error as before: no response.

I have both pip.exe and pip3.5.exe in the Scripts folder. Don't know if that's correct or not.

Comment: Could it be that the python you're running the script with is actually python 2?

Comment: Verify if `pip --version` and `python --version` are using the same version of Python?

Comment: can you find the tweepy package by calling `pip list`?

Comment: can you do a `which pip`? you might be installing the package into a different version/install to the python used in your script

Comment: heheh... 4 comments on the same idea within 11 seconds of each other :)

Comment: You haven't mention the OS you're using. `which pip` will tell you which pip you're running on a unix-like OS. `pip3` is the command a python3 pip typically install.

Comment: Edited to respond to suggestions...